# Absolute url in hugo website front matter _index.md file

Tags: yaml, hugo, wowchemy

I'm stuck at the following issue being a new in Hugo. I want to redirect `URL` to a absolute URL rather than `relative url`. Here is what I means.
In _index.md file

```
# Display name
title: mohit kumar
url: ranveeriit.github.io/
```

Assume base URL is `https://eample.com`. As such, hugo redirects me to `https://example.com/ranveeriit.github.io/` what I want hugo to redirect to `ranveeriit.github.io/` when I click the  `mohit kumar` under meet the team at `https://chandu8542.github.io/`. I'm using hugo wowchemy academic theme.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit your theme's `/layouts/` files to add support to your particular use-case.

1. It may be in `index.html` or `list.html` or some other file, depending on how your theme split up their code.
2. Look for the `<a href="">` part. It more likely looks like `<a href="{{ .Permalink }}">` or `<a href="{{ .RelPermalink}}">`.
3. Change it to something like: `<a href="{{ with .Params.link }}{{ . }}{{ else }}{{ .Permalink }}{{ end }}">`.
4. Then in your `.md` file, add the `link` frontmatter param. It should look similar to this:

```yaml
---
link: https://example.com
---
```

Comment: thanks for the ans. I'm not able to find the file/place to modify. Could you help me out? `_index.md` is available at [link](https://github.com/chandu8542/chandu8542.github.io/tree/master/content/authors/ranveer). Index.html or list.html is not present in layouts.

Comment: Hmm… I'm not familiar with your theme, I tried visiting github.com/wowchemy/wowchemy-hugo-modules/wowchemy but Github is returning 404 yet it is in your config file as a module. Without access to the theme's source, it's impossible to help in this case, probably best to contact wowchemy.

Regardless, you just have to find which file your theme placed {{ .Permalink }} or {{ .RelPermalink }} and edit it accordingly to support a new Param. Some complicated themes, like I think what wowchemy is, probably have it deep somewhere, you'll have to track down how their theme works to find it.